# System.AccessViolationException on OleDbConnection.Query using Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, oledb, dapper

I'm using an `OleDbConnection` in .Net 4.0 to query a Microsoft Access 2010 database with the ACE OleDb 12.0 engine. It's possible that the process executes a high number of queries per second, since I have around 60 possible parallel threads (I set a `ThreadPool` limit for TPL after reading [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B830133)). The mdb file is on a network drive. I create and dispose a connection on each query, with the following code :

```
Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    result = connection.Query(Of Foo)(query, New With {.Param1 = param1, .Param2 = param2}).FirstOrDefault()
End Using
```

From time to time, seemingly randomly, I get a `System.AccessViolationException in System.Data.dll` on the call to `connection.Query`. This exception is supposed to be thrown by unmanaged code, but I don't *directly* use unmanaged code, so it happens after the call to `Query`. I also wanted to make sure it was not a problem obviously related to multi-threading, but, if I understand the documentation correctly, using one `IDbConnection` per query should be thread-safe, and Dapper is supposed to be thread-safe too.

The error doesn't always happen on the same query or POCO type, and it's probably not a problem with the hardware (CPU < 50%, memory < 75% and my process doesn't eat more than 250 MB). I have not yet seen a problem with similar code on a `SqlConnection` to SQL Server.

Additionally, I'm working with VS Express 2012, so even if I configured "Break on exception", I can't use the Exception Assistant to troubleshoot. I obviously don't want to catch the exception up the stack, since it's a memory-related exception (as I wouldn't want to catch an OutOfMemoryException).

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to debug this, since it happens only from time to time? Could this be a bug with Dapper or the OleDb engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue would be having multiple threads hitting the Access DB.  As far as I am aware, `MS Access` **isn't** designed for `multi-threaded` applications, since it has a limit on concurrency.

There's isn't much documentation on it, but it mentions [`here`](http://www.teamits.com/internet/support/nt/msaccess_limitations.html) that MS Access isn't designed for high stress and high concurrency.

**EDIT**: Based on comments

1. You could dump the access database directly into SQL Server, as a staging process and then run your .Net code against the Data in the staging table into it's final table on SQL.
2. Use [`SSIS data flow to manipulate the data`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505848.aspx), possibly using a Script task for the .Net code
3. I have seen a process where [`Reactive Extensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229813%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) were being used on large 2gb CSV files, using the buffer to stream the data.  So, if you can dump the ms access data into a CSV, you could run a similar process in memory.

Comment: I found elsewhere (can't find it in my history) that Access is supposed to support up to 255 concurrent connections, and [the article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B830133) I mentioned in my question sets a limit at 64 connections per process. While I'm aware that Access is not necessarily fit for my needs (in fact, the problem arises in a data migration job from Access to a new SQL Server database), I can't see why it would not handle a couple dozens read-only connections. I could try to lower the maximum number of threads, but I would never know for sure.

Comment: @BenjaminBeaulieu, I remember working on small web applications years ago with Access, and more than a few users could bring it down.  Are you using TPL to migrate the data? Can you not export to CSV and then use SSIS to load the data to SQL?

Comment: We use .Net to re-validate, transform (format and structure) and migrate the data from Access to SQL Server. I don't think there's an all-in-one tool that would allow us to go as deep as we go with custom .Net code. The performance is very important too, since we only have a small time window to migrate all the data each day.

Comment: I have updates the answer with some alternate solutions.  How large would a CSV dump of the MS Access DB be?

Comment: I considered using your first solution (dump Access into SQL Server, then query from there), but the Migration Assistant in Access throws an error and cannot complete the migration (totally different problem). Even if it worked, the migration should be able to run automatically each day, so using the assistant is not really an option.
Obviously, migrating the data from Access to a staging area in SQL Server with .Net code would probably lead me into the same problem I have right now.

Comment: For the CSV file, I have to assume that it could grow pretty fast beyond a couple of GB, so it could not be a long-term solution. However, I like your idea of processing "chunks" of data in-memory. I'll try to see if a caching mechanism could help me unload some of the stress off the Access database.

Comment: Shouldn't the long term solution be to switch off writing data to Access?

Comment: We are planning on moving away from Access, but I can't tell when/if it will actually happen. The Access database is currently part of an operational system, and the SQL Server database will be used as a data warehouse for reporting/data analysis from multiple operational systems. The plan is to move all the operational systems on SQL Server, but it could take a while. Anyhow, the migration will need to adapt pretty easily to a database change.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it mentions a possible high stress problem with Access. I ended up caching most of the tables I needed for the migration, so it executes a lot less queries.

Comment: code sample for process Reactive Extensions using the buffer to stream the data ? maybe in github ?